# Форматирование телефонного номера: регулярное выражение

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Програма принимает на ввод мобильный телефон.

Програма должна отформатировать телефонный номер к единому значению.

> 063 999-99-99 возвращает (+38) 063 999-99-99
>
> 063-99999-99 возвращает (+38) 063 999-99-99
>
> +3806399-999-99 возвращает (+38) 063 999-99-99
>
> 380639999999 возвращает (+38) 063 999-99-99

Сделал регулярку которая соответсвует формату

```
r'\(\+38\)\s\d{3}\s\d{3}[\-]\d{2}[\-]\d{2}'
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как избежать перебора всевозможных вариантов. Сделать так чтобы инпут номер приходил к нужному формату без тонны **if, elif, else**. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

можно попробовать так:

```
import re

def num_form(a: str) -> str:
    a=re.sub(r"\D","", a)
    res = re.sub(r"(.*?)(.{3})(.{3})(.{2})(.{2})$", r"(+38) \2 \3-\4-\5", a)
    return res

print(num_form("063 999-99-99"))
print(num_form("063-99999-99"))
print(num_form("+3806399-999-99"))
print(num_form("380639999999"))
```

```
(+38) 063 999-99-99
(+38) 063 999-99-99
(+38) 063 999-99-99
(+38) 063 999-99-99
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе огромное!)) как раз то что нужно было !!! Спасибо